# I brought a hibernating yellow jacket queen into my house accidentally. What will happen?

Tags: entomology

There was apparently a hibernating yellow jacket queen in my stack of firewood outside.  An hour or so after bringing in the firewood, we saw the queen fly off into the house, where we can't find her.

What will happen?  Will she lay her eggs and start a nest somewhere in our house?  Will she just find somewhere and go back to sleep?

Comment: I'd just sell the house and move as quickly as you can... ;)

Comment: lol, that doesn't seem like too bad of an idea at the moment :-)

Comment: She will likely die somewhere unseen in the house, probably by a window. She won't dive bomb anyone, though, if that's what you're worried about. We used to find a dead queen every year in our old house. Never understood why.

Comment: Well; if mostly your house is sanitized; poor queen will die somewhere in the house. Queens are not "designed" to attack; so I wouldn't have worried about it if I were you........Only, I couldn't get my eyes closed at night :D.

Comment: *Yellow jacket* is a very general term, that covers a wide variety of species with different biologies. Can you be more specific?